# Find the range of values for k for which the equation $x^2+(a-2)x+(a+3)=0$ had no real roots

Tags: quadratics

I don't understand the question at all.

Find the range of values for a for which the equation $x^2+(a-2)x+(a+3)=0$ has no real roots.

Comment: You have to solve this equation and to show, that the term within the square root is negativ for all $a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain values of **a** for which the equation has no real roots. You have to find out which ones.

1. Translate "the equation has no real roots" in mathematical terms (for example, you might use the determinant of the equation).
2. Develop and find a condition on **a**.
3. Conclude and profit.